# Can Goblins conquer Lost Tribe regions for one less token?

Tags: small-world

The goblins race power is to conquer in-decline regions with one less token. Do Lost Tribes count as in-decline regions? Are Lost Tribes considered an in-decline race?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Lost Tribes are considered an in-decline race and can be conquered by Goblins with advantage. Lost Tribes tokens have little broken column symbol, which indicates "in-decline" state in game assets.